# Docker-Compose Creates New Volume After Down & Up (Data is Lost)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to create a [redmine instance](https://hub.docker.com/_/redmine).

This is my `docker-compose.yml`, which is based on the official documentation:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  redmine:
    image: redmine:4.0.4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8890:3000
    environment:
      REDMINE_DB_MYSQL: db
      REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD: password

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: redmine
```

Now, whenever I run `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up`, all of my data (database and files) are deleted, even though I'm not using `-v` flag, which is necessary for deleting volumes.

Also when I run `docker volumes ls`, it seems a new volume is created after each `docker-compose up`.

Is this normal?

How can I use those previous volumes which are created by docker and have a very long hash-based name?

Comment: I guess it is by design. `docker-compose down` is meant to clean-up resources. And probably docker has no way to tell that it has to reuse volume on next `docker-compose up`. If you mean to stop the container you can use `docker-compose stop` instead. Or maybe consider giving volume a name so that docker-compose knows to reuse it.

Answer (score 2):

You havent added volume for database. So database data is lost every time you do `docker-compose down`. If you want to keep data you can add volume like this:

```
  version: '3.1'

    services:
      redmine:
        image: redmine:4.0.4
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 8890:3000
        environment:
          REDMINE_DB_MYSQL: db
          REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD: password

      db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: redmine
        volumes:
          - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign volume settings by using this

first, you need to delete all old mysql data using

```
docker-compose down -v
```

after that add two lines in your docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

and

```
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

your final docker-compose.yml will looks like

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

after that use this command

```
docker-compose up -d
```

now your data will persistent and will not be deleted even after using this command

```
docker-compose down
```

extra:- but if you want to delete all data then you will use

```
docker-compose down -v
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't persist the MySQL Container Data on your host. So yes,  a new fresh instance is created. This is actual Docker behaviour. Please read the MySQL documentation "Where to Store Data" at MySQL docker Hub repo